# What's the usage of event.put("hasAlarm", 0)?

Tags: android, events, calendar

When you add a event in the calendar

```
String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", KeyStoreController.getKeyStore(mContext).isIDCalendar(mContext));
    event.put("dtstart", startTime);//startTimee+1000 * 60 * 60* 2);
        event.put("dtend", endTime);                                                             
    event.put("eventStatus", 1);event.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1);
```

I don't know what does "hasAlam" do?
Any ideas? I hope that somebody can help me.